# Can you test a skill that you have developed yourself on the Alexa app (on your phone)?

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, echodot

I have finished developing my skill on my console and I would like to make a demonstration for my teachers but I do not have the echo dot. I have been trying to use the app to do this, but I didn't find how.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alexa app itself to talk to Alexa.

1. Open Alexa app
2. Click on the Alexa logo.

[image]

Another alternative is to use third party apps. For a long time I was using an Android app called [Reverb](https://reverb.ai/). It has an iOS version too.